# Deluge script not updating values after input values changed

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I wrote the following Deluge script to multiply fields together and map the output to other fields. It works as it should initially but if I edit one of the 1st or 2nd fields the 3rd field updates but the 5th does not. Any help on why this is?

```
r_account = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Accounts",AccountID);
 
value1 = r_account.get("Decimal_1");

value2 = r_account.get("Decimal_2");

value3 = r_account.get("Decimal_3");

value4 = r_account.get("Decimal_4");

output = value1 * value2;

output2 = value3 * value4;

updatemap = Map();

updatemap.put("Decimal_3",output);
updatemap.put("Decimal_5",output2);

response = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Accounts",AccountID,updatemap);
info response;
```

Comment: How did you run this function? Via workflow rules? On what event is it? Create/Edit/Create-Edit?

Answer (score 0):

01-07-2023

I took a fresh look at the question.

It looks like the `1st or 2nd fields` are `r_account.get("Decimal_1")` as field1 (value1)  and `r_account.get("Decimal_2")` as field2 (value2).  However, there isn't any code in the example showing either of these fields getting edited.  If they are edited after `value3 = r_account.get("Decimal_3");` is set, then `value3` in the following code would represent the initial value of `value3` and it wouldn't change.

```
output2 = value3 * value4;
updatemap.put("Decimal_5",output2);
```

To solve this, make sure that `value3` contains the value of Decimal_3 after this line runs:

```
updatemap.put("Decimal_3",output);
```

and before this line:

```
output2 = value3 * value4;
```

########################################################
Pre 01-07-2023 Answer below
########################################################

I'm not sure what is going on but try these debugging suggestions:

1.
Display the updatemap data structure just before the call to `updateRecord()` to make sure it has the data you expect:

```
...
updatemap = Map();

updatemap.put("Decimal_3",output);
updatemap.put("Decimal_5",output2);

// This is the new bit to display the updatemap data.
info updatemap;

response = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Accounts",AccountID,updatemap);
...
```

2. 

Try running a separate call to `updateRecord()` for each `output` item.  Example:

```
...
updatemap1 = Map();

updatemap1.put("Decimal_3",output);


response = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Accounts",AccountID,updatemap1);
info response;

updatemap2 = Map();
updatemap2.put("Decimal_5",output2);
response2 = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Accounts",AccountID,updatemap2);

info response2;
...
```